# Magento Varien Object not Saving data

Tags: php, magento, model

I'm trying to use setData in my Address object.
Here is the code:

```
//code inside another class
$this->getAddress()->setData('abc', 'abc')->collectShippingRates()->save();

class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address extends Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract
{
...
    public function collectShippingRates()
    {
        ...

        $found = $this->requestShippingRates();
        ...

        return $this;
    }
    public function requestShippingRates(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item = null)
    {
        //I knkow it's getting here, because when I echo 'blablabla', it works.
        //When I use $this->setData('abc', 'abc') here, the code bellow print 'abc'
        //The problem is when I use setData outside the class
        echo $this->getData('abc');exit; //prints nothing
        ...
    }
...
}
```

As you can see, I setData in my Address model, but inside the class getData returns nothing.
Can someone please explain what's happening?
When I try to use Mage::register, it does not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible avenues of exploration.

1. Your call to `getAddress` isn't returning a `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` object, or is returning a different instance of an address object.
2. Your call to `setData('abc', 'abc')` happens later in Magento's code execution than the first call to `requestShippingRates`.
3. Code between your call to `getAddress` and the execution of `requestShippingRates` is re-instantiating or initializing the address object.

Based on your comments about `Mage::register`, my money is on number two.

Comment: It appears `requestShippingRates` is being executed before calling `collectShippingRates`. If I print microtime in my Block class (the class where `$this->getAddress()->setData('abc', 'abc')->collectShippingRates()->save();` is executed), it's a time later than microtime printed inside `requestShippingRates`, even though the `requestShippingRates` method comes later in the code.

Comment: @VictorMachado It seems more likely that requestShippingRates is called twice than PHP is executing code out of sequence :)

Comment: Yes. It's true. Saw this: `if (!$this->getCollectShippingRates()) { return $this; }` before `requestShippingRates`. Thanks Alan. Helped me a lot.